# Cannot print data base object (PyMongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I just started learning NoSQL in school and I keep getting
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/balaji/Others/sssss.py", line 3, in <module> databases = client.database_names() TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable`

this error when I try to run

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017)
databases = client.database_names()
print("The databases in the MongoDB server are:")
print(databases)
client.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`MongoClient.database_names()` is [deprecated and removed since `pymongo` version 4.0](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=database_names). Use [`MongoClient.list_database_names()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.list_database_names) instead.